# Defining typeliases declared in other protocols

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols

I'm creating a protocol that extends from `CollectionType`, however, I'm introducing new typealiases that eliminate the need for `Element` in `CollectionType` (or rather, they allow me to compute it).

I'll use a simple `MapType` protocol as an example:

```
protocol MapType : CollectionType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible {
    typealias Key
    typealias Value

    func updateValue(theNewValue:Value, forKey theKey:Key) -> Value?
}
```

In the above example, what I really need to be able to do is redefine `Element` to be the tuple `(Key, Value)`, but I'm not sure how to do this in a protocol rather than a structure or class.

Simply adding `typealias Element = (Key, Value)` produces no errors, but also doesn't appear to actually do anything within the context of the protocol, for example, the following won't work:

```
extension MapType {
    var firstKey:Key? { return self.generate().next()?.0 }
}
```

This produces an error, as the generator isn't recognised as returning a tuple (i.e- it has no member `.0`).

What is the best way to define `Element` as `(Key, Value)` in this case, such that I can use it within protocol extensions? Is this even possible?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is MapType a collection of, and in what sense is it a collection?

Comment: @matt Seems like `MapType` is roughly an ordered dictionary based on what is here.

Comment: Please note, by the way, that this use of the word "typealias" is going away in Swift 2.2: it will be called "associatedtype".

Comment: The `MapType` was just as a simple example, but it is really a protocol I need to define since we don't have abstract classes (and actually I'm implementing a set of structs). After posting this I explored the possibility of just defining MapType independently of `CollectionType` but it seems like right now there's no perfect option, so `where` clauses  like nhgrif suggested may be my best option for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't necessarily *force* that the `Element` type inherited from the `CollectionType` protocol is necessarily a tuple made up of the `Key` and `Value` types from the `MapType`.

However, we can limit our protocol extension to only add the `firstKey` method to those that do conform to the protocols in such a way using a `where` statement.

Consider this simplified example:

```
protocol Base {
    typealias Element

    func first() -> Element?
}

protocol Child: Base {
    typealias Key
    typealias Value

    func last() -> (Key, Value)?
}

extension Child where Self.Element == (Self.Key, Self.Value) {
    var firstKey:Key? { return self.first()?.0 }
}

struct ChildStruct: Child {
    func first() -> (String, Int)? {
        return ("Foo", 1)
    }

    func last() -> (String, Int)? {
        return ("Bar", 2)
    }
}

let c = ChildStruct()
let first = c.first()
let firstKey = c.firstKey
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to create a `where` clause inside of a protocol. That's not possible in Swift today. You can not constrain associated types based on other associated types. Someday maybe, but not today.

You'll need to rethink how you're attacking the problem. The likely solution is to use a generic struct rather than a protocol (otherwise you tend to wind up with a lot of duplicated `where` clauses all over your code). You can see this recent [dotSwift talk](http://www.thedotpost.com/2016/01/rob-napier-beyond-crusty-real-world-protocols) for more detailed examples.